# content placeholder going down due to vertical menu bar

Tags: html, css, asp.net, master-pages

I am trying to create a master page with vertical menubar and the content should show beside the menubar. Just like a normal web page having vertical menu bar in the left side and contents side by it.

But the content is pushed below the side bar. How can fix this design issue? Please help. Attached is the screen shot.

My master page

```
<%@ Master Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="Layout.master.cs" Inherits="FMS.UIWebUsers.Layout" %>

<!DOCTYPE html>

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
    <title></title>
    <link href="../../css/navigationMenu.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <asp:ContentPlaceHolder ID="head" runat="server">
    </asp:ContentPlaceHolder>
</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
        <div id="menu12">
            <ul>
                <li>
                    <div class="bt1">
                        <span class="ht11">»&nbsp;</span>
                        <span class="hw12">Navigation Menu</span>
                    </div>
                </li>
                <li><a title="Home" href="#">Home</a></li>
                <li><a title="Photos" href="#">Photo Gallery</a></li>
                <li><a title="Events" href="#">Events Calendar</a></li>
                <li><a title="Forum" href="#">Community</a></li>
                <li><a title="Articles" href="#">Article Directory</a></li>
                <li><a title="Link Directory" href="#">Link Directory</a></li>
                <li><a title="Download" href="#">Freeware Download</a></li>
            </ul>
        </div>
        <div>
            <asp:ContentPlaceHolder ID="ContentPlaceHolder1" runat="server">
            </asp:ContentPlaceHolder>
        </div>

    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

css for the vertical menu bar

```
#menu12 {
width: 178px;
padding: 0 0 0 0;
margin-bottom: 1em;
font-size: 11px;
font-weight: normal;
font-family: Verdana, Lucida, Geneva, Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
background-color: #6898d0;
color: #333;
}
#menu12 ul {
list-style: none;
margin: 0;
padding: 0;
border: none;
}       
#menu12 li {
border-bottom: 1px solid #90bade;
margin: 0;
width: auto;
}
#menu12 li a {
display: block;
padding: 3px 0px 3px 0.5em;
border-left: 5px solid #8AA1B6;
border-right: 5px solid #8AA1B6;
background-color: #6898d0;
color: #fff;
text-decoration: none;
width: auto;
}
#menu12 li a:hover {
border-left: 5px solid #800000;
border-right: 5px solid #800000;
background-color: #FF7C3E;
color: #fff;
}
.bt1 {
width : auto;
font-family : Verdana, Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;  
font-size : 10px; 
text-align : left; 
font-weight : bold; 
color : #ffffff; 
background-color : #8AA1B6; 
padding-top : 3px; 
padding-bottom : 4px; 
padding-left : 4px; 
border-left: 5px solid #FF7C3E;
display : block; 
}
.ht11 {
font-size : 10px; 
font-weight: bold;
color : #000;  
font-family : Verdana, Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; 
text-decoration : none; 
}   
.hw12 {
font-size : 11px; 
font-weight : bold; 
color : #ffffff; 
font-family : verdana, arial, helvetica, sans-serif;
text-decoration : none; 
}
```

My webpage code

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" MasterPageFile="~/Layout.Master" CodeBehind="WebForm1.aspx.cs" Inherits="FMS.UIWebUsers.WebForm1" %>

<asp:Content ID="BodyContent" ContentPlaceHolderID="ContentPlaceHolder1" runat="server">
    <h2><%: Title %>.</h2>
    <h3>Your application description page.</h3>
    <p>Use this area to provide additional information.</p>
</asp:Content>
```

[image]

Comment: add float:left for the menu

Comment: thank you solve the problem.